# I am using VSCode and Python to program a RPI Zero 2. I want use VSCode for coding and Jupiter Notebooks to debug. Each in there own windows in VS

Tags: jupyter-notebook, raspberry-pi

I have tried to set it up but with zero success.  I would like to find step-by-step directions, please. I am a novice using VS Code and Jupiter Notebooks.  Thank you

I have set up VS Code and have it working with SSH to the RPI. I am having trouble getting the Jupiter Notebooks in a window with VS Code and debugging my code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.